# .NET SDK requirement for Saturn

Tags: f#, saturn-framework

When following the "How to start" guide for Saturn:

https://saturnframework.org/tutorials/how-to-start.html

Step 4 says to run:

```
dotnet tool restore
```

Here's the result of running that on my system:

```
PS C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\SaturnSample> dotnet tool restore
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application 'tool' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      A compatible installed .NET SDK for global.json version [3.1.200] from [C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\SaturnSample\global.json] was not found.
      Install the [3.1.200] .NET SDK or update [C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\SaturnSample\global.json] with an installed .NET SDK:
        3.1.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
        5.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
        5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

I see a few ways forward:

- Install .NET SDK version 3.1.200 (even though I already have 3.1.405)
- Update global.json to be the following:

```
{
    "sdk": {
      "version": "3.1.405"
    }
  }
```

- Update global.json to be the following (allows for versions more recent than 3.1.200):

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.200",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```

Which of these would be recommended for Saturn?

## UPDATE

Looks like there's a pull-request regarding this issue:

https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn.Template/pull/29

## UPDATE 2021-02-10

The above mentioned pull request isn't ideal since it requires a specific version of the .NET SDK.

I've submitted a pull-request to go with the `rollForward` option:

https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn.Template/pull/31

Comment: You can just remove global.json

Comment: @nilekirk I wouldn't recommend removing `global.json`.